# how to use compression with scribe?

Tags: compression, scribe

i use scribe to collect logs. my question is how to compress data before send ?
i know scribe use thrift ,and thrift support tzlibtransport ,but i donn't know how to use it. ( For some reasons,we cann't use ssh tunnel.)

thanks!